# Oracle JOIN 3 tables - Which way is efficient or is there any difference at all

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I can see people doing joins in different ways

> select a.acc, b.acc, c.acc from a, b,c
>   where a.acc=b.acc and c.acc = a.acc;

and

> select a.acc, b.acc, c.acc JOIN on
>   a.acc=b.acc JOIN on c.acc = a.acc;

Is there any difference? I suppose not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of performance there is no difference.

I prefer the second approach for maintainability. It is more explicit which conditions are used to join which tables and it is easier to see whether or not you have missed out a join condition.

Comment: is there a reason why you prefer the second approach?

Comment: the second example is ANSI-92 complaint while the first example is ANSI-89 compliant...the ANSI-92 standard is the more preferred

Comment: While there should be no performance difference, there have been a reasonable number of bugs where Oracle chooses the incorrect query plan when the SQL 99 syntax is used (more likely when you're doing some sort of outer join).  99.9% of the time, there is no difference, but it occasionally jumps up to bite you (less often in later releases, of course).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Mark's point that using the latter syntax helps ensure that you don't inadvertently miss a join condition, one nice thing about the SQL 99 syntax is that if your column naming convention is that the name of the column in the parent and child table matches, you can use the USING clause rather than the ON clause, i.e.

```
SELECT <<list of columns>>
  FROM a JOIN b USING( acc )
         JOIN c USING( acc )
```

This can improve the readability of the code and decrease the probability that you introduce errors by inadvertently joining tables incorrectly.  If I had a nickel for every time I accidentally wrote something like

```
SELECT <<list of columns>>
  FROM a,
       a_to_b,
       b
 WHERE a.a_id = a_to_b.a_id
   AND b.b_id = a_to_b.a_id -- a_to_b.**a_id** rather than a_to_b.**b_id**
```

when I really meant

```
SELECT <<list of columns>>
  FROM a,
       a_to_b,
       b
 WHERE a.a_id = a_to_b.a_id
   AND b.b_id = a_to_b.b_id
```

I'd be a rich man.  Or at least have enough for a good sushi dinner.

Most of the time, of course, it's immediately obvious that you've done something wrong because the data is completely screwy but it occasionally happens that the results are sufficiently close that it's not immediately obvious that you've done something wrong and it's not until much later that you discover the bug and track down the culprit query.  It's basically impossible to make that sort of mistake if you write the query with the USING clause

```
SELECT <<list of columns>>
  FROM a JOIN a_to_b USING (a_id)
         JOIN b      USING (b_id)
```

Comment: @PaulVargas - I didn't bother to create the tables `A` and `B` so I didn't use a tool to format the SQL.  I just typed it in here.

Answer (score 3):

if your second select is to read `select a.acc, b.acc, c.acc from a JOIN b on a.acc=b.acc JOIN c on c.acc = a.acc;` then there is no difference.